# Refusal of UK visit visa from Nigeria

Tags: uk, nigerian-citizens

I applied for a visit visa, but was refused under 4.2 appendix V. I declared that I have other means of income in my personal letter, and also gave two statements of account. They ignored the one that has enough money and went for the other one that has a low balance. They wrote me that they are not satisfied that the funds in the account are genuinely available for exclusive use.

I want to know what to do if am reapplying.

These are the relevant sections from the refusal letters:

[image]

[image]

Comment: They might not think the other income is genuinely available for your use. Did you evidence how you are earning from your second source about double what you earn from your main job?

Comment: Yes my other bank statement shows it all and also a document backing my other source of income they ignored everytjinv and said i didnt mention my other source of income

Comment: You posted another question about re applying. The standard advice is to consult a lawyer with UK immigration expertise before making a second or subsequent application after a refusal.

Answer (score 3):

### All information has to match

As the letter states, there is a mismatch between your claims and your account statements.

If you have declared that you earn 500,000 NGN a month as CEO of Royal Ekomex Resources Nigeria Limited and have no other income, and your account statements show 6 month deposits of 5,265,800 NGN, then obviously that demonstrates that your declaration is not fully truthful, because both of these things can't be true at once.

The key part here is not about looking at the account with sufficient money but about getting a trustworthy perspective on your finances - if it seems that parts of the declaration aren't fully truthful, then that's an automatic reason to not trust anything in the declaration and decline the application.

Comment: My other account states it all about my monthly income and when filling the form i stated that i have other source of income but it was ignored instead the consular said i stated that i have no other source of income when i made it clear there that i have other source of income even with supportig documents to that effect.